# Made a game for a website using javascript that asks multiplication questions but having trouble adapting this to perform addition questions

Tags: javascript

This is my multiplication game made using javascript which asks the user to answer questions and provides feedback. the game currently performs multiplication questions and I want it to ask the user addition questions without changing the parameters of the game. I want the game to display the same and function exactly like my multiplication game except it performs addition instead of multiplication using random numbers.

```
     var Counter = {
         PlayingState: null,
         IsStoped: true,
         Score: 0,
         TimeRemaining: 0,
         FirstNumber: 0,
         SecondNumber: 0,
         CorrectAnswer: 0,
         CorrectPosition: 0,
         WrongAnswer: 0,
         AddContentToElement: function(selector, content)
         {
             document.querySelector(selector).innerHTML = content;
         },
         ChangeStyle: function(selector, property, value)
         {
             document.querySelector(selector).setAttribute(property, value);
         },
         Initialize: function(timeRemaining)
         {
             this.TimeRemaining = timeRemaining;
         },
         GenerateRandomNumber: function(multiplier)
         {
             return Math.round( Math.random() * multiplier ) + 1;
         },
         Refresh: function(selector, data)
         {
             document.querySelector(selector).innerText = (data < 10 ? "0" : "") + data;
         },
         LoopThroughElements: function()
         {
             var answers = [this.CorrectAnswer];

             for (var index = 1; index < 5; index++)
             {
                 this.ChangeStyle("ul#choices > li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")", "style", "height:auto;");

                 if (index !== this.CorrectPosition)
                 {
            do
            {
                this.WrongAnswer = this.GenerateRandomNumber(9) * this.GenerateRandomNumber(9);
            } while ( answers.indexOf(this.WrongAnswer) > -1 );

            this.AddContentToElement( "ul#choices > li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")", this.WrongAnswer );
            answers.push(this.WrongAnswer);
        }
    }
},
Launch: function()
{
    this.IsStoped = false;
    this.Action();
    this.ChangeStyle("aside#time-remaining", "style", "visibility:visible;");
    this.ChangeStyle("#game-over", "style", "display:none;");
    this.ChangeStyle("ul#choices", "style", "pointer-events:initial; opacity:1;");
    this.ChangeStyle("button#start-reset", "style", "visibility:hidden;");
    this.AddContentToElement("button#start-reset", "Reset Game");
    this.Refresh("aside#time-remaining > span", this.TimeRemaining);
    this.GenerateQuestionAndAnswers();
},
GenerateQuestionAndAnswers: function()
{
    this.FirstNumber = this.GenerateRandomNumber(9);
    this.SecondNumber = this.GenerateRandomNumber(9);
    this.CorrectAnswer = this.FirstNumber * this.SecondNumber;
    this.CorrectPosition = this.GenerateRandomNumber(3);
    this.ChangeStyle("section#question", "style", "height:auto;");
    this.AddContentToElement("section#question", this.FirstNumber + "x" + this.SecondNumber);
    this.AddContentToElement( "ul#choices > li:nth-of-type(" + this.CorrectPosition + ")", this.CorrectAnswer );
    this.LoopThroughElements();
},
Action: function()
{
    Counter.PlayingState = setInterval( function()
    {
        Counter.TimeRemaining--;

        if (Counter.TimeRemaining <= 50)
        {
            Counter.ChangeStyle("button#start-reset", "style", "visibility:visible;");
        }

        if (Counter.TimeRemaining < 1)
        {
            Counter.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
            Counter.Refresh("aside#time-remaining > span", Counter.TimeRemaining);
        }
    }, 1000 );
},
EventListener: function(event)
{
    if ( Number(event.currentTarget.innerText) === Number(Counter.CorrectAnswer) )
    {
        Counter.Score++;
        Counter.Refresh("aside#score > span", Counter.Score);
        Counter.GenerateQuestionAndAnswers();
        Counter.ChangeStyle("p#message", "style", "visibility:visible; background-color:#23A230;");
        Counter.AddContentToElement("p#message", "Correct");
    }
    else
    {
        if (Counter.Score >= 1)
        {
            Counter.Score -= 0.5;
            Counter.Refresh("aside#score > span", Counter.Score);
        }

        Counter.ChangeStyle("p#message", "style", "visibility:visible; background-color:#DE401A;");
        Counter.AddContentToElement("p#message", "Try again");
    }

    setTimeout( function()
    {
        Counter.ChangeStyle("p#message", "style", "visibility:hidden;");
    }, 1000 );
},
CheckClickOnRightAnswer: function()
{
    for (var index = 1; index < 5; index++)
    {
        document.querySelector("ul#choices > li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").removeEventListener("click", this.EventListener, false);
        document.querySelector("ul#choices > li:nth-of-type(" + index + ")").addEventListener("click", this.EventListener);
    }
},
Stop: function()
{
    this.IsStoped = true;
    clearInterval(this.PlayingState);
    this.ChangeStyle("ul#choices", "style", "pointer-events:none; opacity:0.4;");
    this.ChangeStyle("aside#time-remaining", "style", "visibility:hidden;");
    this.ChangeStyle("div#game-over", "style", "display:block;");
    this.AddContentToElement("button#start-reset", "Start Game");
    this.AddContentToElement( "div#game-over > p:last-of-type > span", (this.Score !== "00" && this.Score < 10 ? "0" : "") + this.Score );
    this.AddContentToElement("aside#score > span", this.Score = "00");
         }
     };


     document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
     {
         document.getElementById("start-reset").addEventListener("click", function()
         {
             Counter.Initialize(60);
             Counter.IsStoped ? Counter.Launch() : Counter.Stop();
             Counter.CheckClickOnRightAnswer();
         });
     });
```

Comment: Hi Jack, Welcome to SO. It seems that you have stated your wish but fail to present us with a problem to help you solve. Could you explain what problems you run into or what does not seem to work?

Comment: hello thanks very much for your response, my problem is that I am trying to turn this multiplication game into a game that tests the users addition skill instead of multiplication so far any changes ive made have broken the game and caused the questions not to display. im very new to coding so any help and pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
this.CorrectAnswer = this.FirstNumber * this.SecondNumber;
```

to this

```
this.CorrectAnswer = this.FirstNumber + this.SecondNumber;
```

and probably change this

```
 this.WrongAnswer = this.GenerateRandomNumber(9) * this.GenerateRandomNumber(9);
```

to this

```
 this.WrongAnswer = this.GenerateRandomNumber(9) + this.GenerateRandomNumber(9);
```